# Database Room Dao Getter return null for the list of country

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

My property doesnt display my list of country whom come from database.

There's the dao,

```
@Dao
interface CountryDataBaseDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM DatabaseCountryProperty")
  fun getData() : LiveData<List<DatabaseCountryProperty>>

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  fun insertData(data : List<DatabaseCountryProperty>)
}
```

There is the ViewModelCountry,

```
class CountryInfoViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

   private val dataCountryRepository = DataCountryRepository(DataDataBase.getInstance(application))

   val data : LiveData<List<DevByteCountryProperty>> = dataCountryRepository.data

   init {
     refreshDataFromRepository()
   }


   private fun refreshDataFromRepository() {
       viewModelScope.launch {
           try {
               dataCountryRepository.refreshData()

               Timber.i("DEBUG : CountryProperties received ${data.value}")
           } catch (e: Exception) {

           }
       }
  }
}
```

When I want my list of DatabaseCountryProperty from the getData(), it return null.

Timber info,

```
4668-4668/com.example.soccerinfo I/CountryInfoViewModel$refreshDataFromRepository: DEBUG : CountryProperties received null
```

The repository,

```
class DataCountryRepository(private val database: DataDataBase ) {

// We recup all the data with getter from database
val data : LiveData<List<DevByteCountryProperty>> = Transformations.map(database.countryDataBaseDao.getData()){
    it.asDomainModel()
}

// We recup the data from network and refresh the database
suspend fun refreshData() : Unit {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        Timber.d("refresh data is called")
        val dataCountry = SoccerApi.retrofitService.getProperties()
        database.countryDataBaseDao.insertData(dataCountry.asDataBaseModel())
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please show how you defined `refreshData()` in your repository. I think you’re checking the value of the LiveData too soon. After the data is refreshed, Room will queue an update of the LiveData, but your coroutine might resume before that happens. Try putting `yield()` right before the Timber call.

Comment: I put yield() before the Timber call but it doesnt work too. The repository was added to the question, you can check.